# Swift Xcode cant remove Embedded binaries / Linked frameworks and libraries from project

Tags: ios, xcode, alamofire

I installed Alamofire by:
dragging **Alamofire.xcodeproj** file into my project navigator, then in
**Project > General > Embedded Binaries**, I clicked on the plus sign and selected **Alamofire.framework**. And it got integrated with no problem.

But how do I now remove it form my project ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove it with the by selecting `Target` and then selecting framework in `Linked Frameworks and Libraries`

if you don't succeed in this way you can then probably check the `Search Path` of both of your `Target` and `Project`

I was having the same problem and my frameworks were not being removed then i cleared the `Search Path` of my `Project`

Answer (score 0):

In some cases, after removing everything, the App will still recognize the library and compile with no errors.
In this case, the App folder in `DerivedData` needs to be removed.